# Javascript - How do i find the current number in a nodelist/querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I am currently working on a vertical javascript image slider, i am trying to make it dynamic so that i can have more than 1 slider using the same code.. everything works fine except that i cant target the current wrapper..

How do i know which wrapper is currently being used?

I tried to browse the STO for a while but could only find some very old answers, we now have 2017 is there any real solution to this problem?

HTML/PHP which generates the sliders

```
<div  class="profileCosplaysWrapper">
    <div id="slideLeftVerticalSlider" class="slideLeftVerticalSlider"><div class="slideLeftVerticalIcon"></div></div>
    <div id="slideRightVerticalSlider" clasS="slideRightVerticalSlider"><div class="slideRightVerticalIcon"></div></div>
    <div id="profileCosplayImageWrapper" class="profileCosplayImageWrapper">
        <?php
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            ?>
            <a class="profileCosplayInnerWrapper" href="index.php?page=cosplay&id=<?php echo $profileCosplayId; ?>">
                <!--<div class="profileCosplayInnerWrapper">-->
                    <img class="profileCosplayImages" src="uploads/<?php echo $profileCosplays; ?>" alt="rate a cosplay latest 10 profile cosplays">
                <!--</div>-->
            </a>
            <?php
        }
        $stmt->close();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div  class="profileCosplaysWrapper">
    <div id="slideLeftVerticalSlider" class="slideLeftVerticalSlider"><div class="slideLeftVerticalIcon"></div></div>
    <div id="slideRightVerticalSlider" clasS="slideRightVerticalSlider"><div class="slideRightVerticalIcon"></div></div>
    <div id="profileCosplayImageWrapper" class="profileCosplayImageWrapper">
        <?php
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            ?>
            <a class="profileCosplayInnerWrapper" href="index.php?page=cosplay&id=<?php echo $profileCosplayRandomId; ?>">
                <!--<div class="profileCosplayInnerWrapper">-->
                    <img class="profileCosplayImages" src="uploads/<?php echo $profileCosplaysRandom; ?>" alt="rate a cosplay latest 10 profile cosplays">
                <!--</div>-->
            </a>
            <?php
        }
        $stmt->close();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var slideLeftVerticalSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.slideLeftVerticalSlider');
    var slideRightVerticalSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.slideRightVerticalSlider');
    var imagesWrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.profileCosplayImageWrapper');
    var profileRightInterval;
    var profileLeftInterval;

    slideLeftVerticalSlider.forEach(function(e){
        e.addEventListener('mouseover', profileMouseOverLeft, false);
    });
    slideRightVerticalSlider.forEach(function(e){
        e.addEventListener('mouseover', profileMouseOverRight, false);
    });
    slideLeftVerticalSlider.forEach(function(e){
        e.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
            clearInterval(profileLeftInterval);
        });
    });
    slideRightVerticalSlider.forEach(function(e){
        e.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
            clearInterval(profileRightInterval);
        });
    });

    function profileMouseOverLeft(e) {
        profileLeftInterval = setInterval(function () {
            profileMoveLeft(0);
        }, 7);
    }
    function profileMouseOverRight(e) {
        profileRightInterval = setInterval(function () {
            profileMoveRight(0);
        }, 7);
    }
    function profileMoveLeft(currentSlider) {
        imagesWrapper[currentSlider].scrollLeft += -5;
    }
    function profileMoveRight(currentSlider) {
        imagesWrapper[currentSlider].scrollLeft += 5;
    }
```

If you look at these functions i am passing "0" as a parameter, which ofcourse should be dynamic

```
function profileMouseOverLeft(e) {
    profileLeftInterval = setInterval(function () {
        profileMoveLeft(0);
    }, 7);
}
function profileMouseOverRight(e) {
    profileRightInterval = setInterval(function () {
        profileMoveRight(0);
    }, 7);
}
function profileMoveLeft(currentSlider) {
    imagesWrapper[currentSlider].scrollLeft += -5;
}
function profileMoveRight(currentSlider) {
    imagesWrapper[currentSlider].scrollLeft += 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this or the [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

```
function profileMouseOverLeft(e) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

based on your HTML using this and parentNode:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".slideLeftVerticalSlider")).forEach( elem => elem.addEventListener("mouseover", left) )
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".slideRightVerticalSlider")).forEach( elem => elem.addEventListener("mouseover", right) )



function left (evt) {
   var wrapper = this.parentNode.querySelector(".profileCosplayImageWrapper")
   wrapper.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function right (evt) {
   var wrapper = this.parentNode.querySelector(".profileCosplayImageWrapper")
   wrapper.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```html
<div  class="profileCosplaysWrapper">
    <div id="slideLeftVerticalSlider1" class="slideLeftVerticalSlider"><div class="slideLeftVerticalIcon">L</div></div>
    <div id="slideRightVerticalSlider1" clasS="slideRightVerticalSlider"><div class="slideRightVerticalIcon">R</div></div>
    <div id="profileCosplayImageWrapper1" class="profileCosplayImageWrapper">
        foo
    </div>
</div>

<div  class="profileCosplaysWrapper">
    <div id="slideLeftVerticalSlider2" class="slideLeftVerticalSlider"><div class="slideLeftVerticalIcon">L</div></div>
    <div id="slideRightVerticalSlider2" clasS="slideRightVerticalSlider"><div class="slideRightVerticalIcon">R</div></div>
    <div id="profileCosplayImageWrapper2" class="profileCosplayImageWrapper">
        foo
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can i retrieve the current nodelist number? like if it is 0,1 or 2 etc :) ?

Comment: If you gave your HTML markup we could give you a better answer than using indexes....

Comment: I honestly have no idea about what you just did... but it did make some cool hover effects on my sliders :D and i managed to customise it so my sliders are now fully functional :)  ohh and thanks

Comment: basically you would just need to do `profileMoveLeft(wrapper)` and change the function to use the element reference
`function profileMoveLeft(currentSlider) {
    currentSlider.scrollLeft += -5;
}`

Comment: Yes everything works as a charm now thanks to you, i am still overwhelmed by this line tho `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".slideLeftVerticalSlider")).forEach( elem => elem.addEventListener("mouseover", left) )` you did some things i havent seen before :)

Comment: FYI: not all browsers support fat arrow syntax and Array.from, using a for loop like you had is valid, just quicker for me to type it that way.

Comment: Hmm yeah okay so far it works in the browsers i am conserned about :)

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler you already have a reference to the element.

You can search the HTMLElementCollection to find the index of that element:

```
function getIndex(element) {
    for(var i=0; i<slideLeftVerticalSlider.length;i++)
    {
        if (slideLeftVerticalSlider[i]===element) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The same method can be applied to any element collection.
You should also be giving every element on your page a unique id.